# Origem do termo "por defeito"

Tags: etimologia, termos, estrangeirismos, neologismos

Eu não tenho certeza se esse termo é pertinente a Portugal, mas notei recentemente o uso crescente do termo "*por defeito*" para se referir a algo que é *padrão*.  Em inglês o termo fica *by default*.

No Brasil não é/era muito comum utiliza-lo, tanto que nas primeiras vezes que me deparei com ele achei que se referia a algum defeito/problema.

Esse termo é comum em outras nações que falam o Português ou foi introduzido pela computação ou algo parecido?

Comment: "*Por defeito*" é a pior tradução que já vi para "*by default*". Afinal de contas, "*default*" em português é traduzido para "*defeito*" da mesma forma que "*the boy is behind the door*" é traduzido para "*o boi está berrando de dor*".

Comment: kkkkkkkkkkkk essa do boi foi demais... kkkkkkkk

Comment: @VictorStafusa melhor que leiaute ;)

Comment: https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/justificado-e-por-defeito/18491

Answer (score 24, accepted):

*Default* não quer dizer *padrão*, e na verdade [tem a mesma raiz etimológica de *fault*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31872/are-fault-and-default-etymologically-related) – em português, *defeito*, *falha*, *falta*.

- Quando um time não comparece a um jogo, **falta**, o outro ganha por *default* (no Brasil, conhecido como W.O.).
- Quando um país não paga suas dívidas, **falha** em pagá-las, decreta a *moratória*, ele está dando um *default* no jargão econômico.
- Em programação, usa-se o valor *default* quando um valor personalizado **falta**, é omitido.

Portanto é compreensível a tradução *por defeito*, embora ela pareça realmente estranha no Brasil – onde é mais comum dizer *valor padrão*.

As alternativas como *por omissão*, e talvez até *por falta*, funcionariam no Brasil, e o primeiro caso parece estar ganhando espaço em Portugal. Mas, sinceramente, a língua é um processo vivo, e o que acredito que acontecerá no Brasil é a consolidação de *por padrão*, e em alguns casos *por default*.

Comment: Foi das melhores respostas que já vi, parabéns.

Comment: No contexto de software, não conheço quem não use "por default". E eu diria que, melhor que "padrão", seria "automático" ou até "pré-definido", se uma tradução é necessária.

Comment: Eu sou informático, e uso sempre "omissão". Como por exemplo: "o valor por omissão é 50."

Answer (score 12):

Em inglês, segundo o [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/default) o termo *default* pode ter o significado de *failure* (**falha, defeito**), por exemplo numa avaria eléctrica, num defeito de fabrico, ou num incumprimento financeiro, mas, nos computadores, o significado é outro: o de um "valor automático escolhido pelo sistema na ausência de intervenção manual em contrário", isto é,  **valor predefinido**. Por isso, neste último caso, a expressão usadas no Brasil, **padrão**, traduz bem o significado indicado naquele dicionário. **Por defeito** é (foi) muito usado em Portugal, no sentido de "falta de intervenção (manual)". A tradução **por omissão** será uma alternativa, e **por predefinição** (ou **por pré-definição**¹) também o seria.

*Adenda.* Como referido no [comentário de user3397179](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/617/origem-do-termo-por-defeito/620#comment1512_618) a entrada ["Justificado e «por defeito»"](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/justificado-e-por-defeito/18491) do Ciberdúvidas da Língua Portuguesa trata do uso em informática da expressão «por defeito».

---

¹ Uso do hífen: "Nas formações com os prefixos tónicos/tônicos acentuados graficamente pós-, pré- e pró-, quando o segundo elemento tem vida à parte (ao contrário do que acontece com as correspondentes formas átonas que se aglutinam com o elemento seguinte): pós-graduação, pós-tónico/pós-tônicos (mas pospor); pré-escolar, pré-natal (mas prever); pró-africano, pró-europeu (mas promover)." -— [AO](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/?action=acordo&version=1991), Base XVI: Do Hífen Nas Formações Por Prefixação, Recomposição E Sufixação.

Answer (score 6):

"Por defeito" é o que chamamos de neologismo, ou ainda, [um "empréstimo semântico"](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/justificado-e-por-defeito/18491).

A expressão "por defeito" seria a declinação natural da expressão "by default" do inglês, mas em países como o Brasil, a expressão correta e mais usada é **"por padrão"**, ou ainda **"por norma"**.

Repare que [o dicionário Michaelis define *defeito* da seguinte forma](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/index.php?lingua=portugues-portugues&palavra=defeito):

> defeito
>
> de.fei.to
>
> **sm (lat defectu)** **1** Imperfeição (física ou moral); balda, deformidade, labéu, mancha, vício. **2** Irregularidade que, num objeto, lhe estraga a aparência, ou lhe causa enfraquecimento, ou lhe prejudica ou impede a utilização; falha, imperfeição: ***Quebrou devido a um defeito do material***. **3** Falta ou escassez de algo essencial à perfeição ou integridade de alguma coisa; deficiência. **4** O que não é conforme às regras da arte. ***D. de massa, Fís***: diferença entre a massa de um isótopo e o seu número de massa, expressa em unidades de massa atômica, assim: o defeito de massa do isótopo de carbônio 6C12, de massa 12,00388, é 0,00388.

[O termo inglês *default* é usado na informática desde 1966](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=default&allowed_in_frame=0).

Comment: Talvez uma boa alternativa a *"por defeito"* seja ***"por omissão"***, no caso de **programas informáticos que assumem determinadas configurações por omissão**, ou "by default", visto que não houve nenhuma indicação quanto ao que deve ser utilizado.

Comment: Nunca tinha ouvido falar de "por omissão". Primeira vez.

Comment: Eu tenho ideia de já ter visto isso usado nalgum software em português de Portugal. Na página ["Justificado e «por defeito» - Ciberdúvidas da Língua Portuguesa"](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/justificado-e-por-defeito/18491) fala-se de como o termo está em ascenção, e de outras traduções alternativas.

Answer (score 1):

By default, no Brasil, para todos os efeitos, "traduz-se" como "por defô" ou não se traduz. "Por defeito" não é uma opção, e sempre resultará em mal-entendido se for usado.

Answer (score 1):

Por defeito não é neologismo, nem se utiliza as mais das vezes nessa acepção. Em matemática, um número apresentado por defeito é o grau de aproximação ao exacto. Ex: um quociente apresentado até às centésimas por defeito. Em contrário temos por excesso.

Comment: Essa matemática......